# Add X and Y labels to latitude/longitude in Altair chart

Tags: python, altair

How do I add the "latitude" and "longitude" labels/titles to the chart? My attempt below is not working.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

chart = alt.Chart(airports).mark_circle().encode(
    longitude=alt.Longitude('longitude:Q', title="Longitude"),
    latitude=alt.Latitude('latitude:Q', title="Latitude"),
    size=alt.value(10),
    tooltip='name'
).project(
    "albersUsa"
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=400
)
```

[image]

Comment: I am no 100%, but I believe that Vega-Lite doesn't support labeled/visible axes for geoviz. You can suggest it as a feature on their issue tracker.